# VBA .datelastmodified returning value + 1 hour

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a method .datelastmodified to get the time and the date of the file when it was last modified. I wrote the code on Friday. It was working perfectly and today for some reason its returning the value plus one additional hour.

I don't know if this is an excel issue, or my PC changed regions or what?

```
Sub test()

    Dim file As Variant
    Dim fso As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Source = "path"

    While (file <> "")

        If InStr(file, "filename") > 0 Then

            Set fils = fso.GetFile(Source & file)
            d = fils.DateLastModified

            Debug.Print d
        End If

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is a summer/winter time issue because of "changing the clocks" during this weekend. Might be different in your location, but at least in Germany we changed clocks from winter to summer time this weekend.

Comment: yes, thank you, Im in Luxembourg, I have been busting my head for the past hour. Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue, and have posted the answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458025/vba-leap-of-1-hour-in-modify-file-information/71289441#71289441](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458025/vba-leap-of-1-hour-in-modify-file-information/71289441#71289441)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a function to fix this issue, something like this. Only thing I don't know is if this will be working in VBA.

```
Public Function GetLastWriteTime(ByVal FilePath As String) As Date
    Return IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(FilePath) _
      .Add(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Now))
End Function
```

Comment: Your code seems to be VB.NET, but there is no `System.IO` in VBA. In VBA you would have to use the `FileSystemObject` instead, as the OP did.